# We have a 200 % increase of "organic" search traffic - how to figure out which keyword is causing this?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, keywords

So our Google Analytics are showing us that 200 % increase of "organic" search traffic. Analytics are saying that search keyword is "(not provided)". We are wondering how to find out which keyword is causing this?

We are monitoring all important keywords for our website. None of the keywords is in the first 5, so our "organic" serach traffic is modest. However, today we received 200 % increase of "organic" search traffic but none of keywords we can think of moved a bit. We also did not change anything related to SEO.

And what is interesting, Google Webmaster shows no changes - ~2500 impressions and ~200 clicks.

How to find out which "keyword" might be causing this spike?

Comment: Are you using Google Analytics? It would be good to mention in your question how you're tracking keywords from incoming SERP visits.

Answer (score 1):

Traffic that shows up under "not provided" is coming from visitors who are logged into Google, which results in the keyword information not being passed to your website. Unfortunately, there is no good way to know what those keywords might be other than guesstimating from the Google Webmaster console.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of ways to identify your incoming traffic. Although all of these methods are guesstimates, they do however provide an approximation to the source of your traffic.

1. Tools such as [SEMrush](https://www.semrush.com), [Sistrix](https://www.sistrix.com) and other keyword position tracking tools
2. [Google Webmaster Tools Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)
3. [Google AdWords Keyword Planning Tool](https://adwords.google.com/aw/keywordplanner/ideas/new)

The last one being a hit or miss method, since it only shows how much search volume exist for keywords where specific pages of yours could have a high enough Quality Factor to be able to bid on.

Look at your Google Webmaster Tools Console, and look for your traffic spike in form of clicks and impressions. This should give you an idea which URLs of yours got promoted. This on the other hand might give you a sense of which keywords are associated with these URLs. If for some reason you can't identify a real spike, but rather a broad long-tailish increase in traffic affecting many URLs, then keyword position tools might help you out (i.e. Sistrix). These monitor the SERPs for keywords for which your pages are found and track any changes in position, also giving you a good indication for which keywords your URLs are found, what position they currently are found at and which URLs are displayed to searchers.

Then you could correlate your newfound information with Google Analytics and you got your pages and their correlating keywords.

EDIT:
Wow, I just realised this question was 5 years old. Nothing to see here, move along.